# Get and combine data from an intermediate tastypie resource

Tags: python, django, model, tastypie

Is there a best practice to add data from an intermediate table to a resource only when the details are requested for that resource?

As an example I will use the Django example models (Person, Group and Membership).

When I get a list of all Person resources (/api/person/) I don't get any group info in the results.

```
[
    {        
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "resourceUri": "/user/1/"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "resourceUri": "/user/2/"
    }
]
```

But when I get the details of one Person resource (/api/person/1/) I want certain Group info in the result. That group info partially comes from both the Group and Membership Model.

```
{
    "resourceUri": "/user/1/",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "groups": [        
        {
            "date_joined": "15/02/1988",
            "name": "administrator"            
        },        
        {            
            "date_joined": "25/05/1992",
            "name": "helpdesk"
        }
    ]
}
```

So basically I'm looking for a way to add additional data to my result. And optionally only when a specific method like getting the details of a resouce is requested. I tried implementing this by overriding the dehydrate method and I succeeded but it felt very hackish and I wonder if there is a best practice for this.

### Django models

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('person', 'group')
```

### TastyPie resources

```py
class Person(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Person.objects.all()
```